# Schema design and dynamic form input constraints

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema

I am working on an e-commerce schema design where a seller is required to submit product information and this information could be generic or category derived. That is, **each category should have some features, whose values *could be constrained* to choose from**. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036376/db-schema-for-dynamic-categories) summarizes the problem and design I have come up with too. That is:

Product

```
Product_ID, Name, Price, Photo, Category_ID
```

Category

```
Category_ID, Name, Parent_ID, isLeafCategory (only a leaf category has products assigned)
```

Category_Field

```
Category_Field_ID, Category_ID, Name, Type, Values (range of values to choose from)
```

Product_Category_Field_Value

```
ID, Product_ID, Category_ID, Category_Field_ID, Value
```

**For instance, suppose for the category "Tables", features and constraints are:**

```
| category_id (ID)  |   name (string)    | type (`enum` field) |             values (array of strings)             | isRequired (Boolean) |
|-------------------|--------------------|---------------------|---------------------------------------------------|----------------------|
|                 1 | "Color"            | SELECT              | ["red","black", "black gray", ... say 36 more]    | True                 |
|                 1 | "Shape"            | SELECT              | ["Rectangular","Round","Square", ... say 19 more] | True                 |
|                 1 | "Storage included" | BOOLEAN             | ["YES", "NO"]                                     | False                |
|                 1 | "Seating capacity" | INT                 | ["0","8"]                                         | False                |
|                 1 | "Brand"            | SELECT              | ["Ikea","Godrej", ... say 1024 more]              | True                 |
|                 1 | "Suitable for"     | SELECT_MULTIPLE     | ["ADULT","CHILDREN","DINING", ... say 6 more]     | False                |
```

**Questions:**

> 1. Is using `type` column (`enum`) the right way to manage HTML form constraint? Or, should form fields be a concern of front-end dev only,
>      and this field is unnecessary in the DB?
> 2. Is using an array of strings the right way to manage constraints on the range of values for datatypes like `boolean` and `number`? Or,
>      should these kinds of constraints be managed at app and server levels,
>      definitely not in DB?
> 3. Should values for a category feature be maintained in a separate table, since array size could be very big (e.g. "brands")?

EDIT: By questions 1 and 2 specifically, I mean if I should think about mapping in all the possibilities into `enum` and ranges?

**EDIT 2: Regarding closing requests, at least let me know in comments what's so obvious or wrong about these questions, because to me they are worth asking?**

Comment: on my last project we had a similar DB Schema dividing every possible type in a separate table. and the general table was showing what, which and where every value could be found. supposedly it was dublin core metadata coherent. 1 was indicating in what table to check 2. was app dependent and deciding what request was to be made 3. values were stored in a separate table divided type, name and calling method input parameters for overloaded function usage

Comment: This is how I interpret your comment @aldr, please correct me! 
1. Instead of `enum`, use a foreign key to `CategoryFeatureType` table.
2. "Don't understand"
3. Another `CategoryFeatureValues` table to store values with a foreign key as `CategoryFeatureId`
I sure am missing points in your 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: 1. for every FeatureType we had an own Table 2. e.g. we had a FeatureType like String or Double, but you could also create your own types that is what I meant by depending on your application, we were happy with the "basic" types 3. exactly any ValueType of all FeatureTypes had at least one entry.

Comment: @aldr I think I get you! Could you please elaborate this as an answer, and I would accept it to close, if no one improves on it at least :)

Comment: **Also**, why not an array of strings for each `values` column?

Comment: at the beginning we had a string array type but we got to the conclusion that we didn't need array types, cause SQL queries delivered everything as a List in a Spring Boot application and our Custom Repositories, so it depends if you want array types or not they are certainly possible

Comment: I'll post an answer tomorrow

Comment: The best way to answer all your questions is to try the choices.  Be willing to change!

Comment: @Rick I won't dare to argue that, but if I could borrow experience of devs like yourself to start with on a judged good road, I would! I request you to kindly add an answer, subjective remarks could set me in the right direction too!